# Left Join and Coalesce multiple variables

Tags: sql, sas

I have 3 data sets:

- `A` containing variables *period, region, city*
- `B` containing variables *period, city, sales1, sales2, sales3*
- `C` containing variables *period, region, sales1, sales2, sales3*

The sample data sets are:

```
  **A:**
  Period    City   Region
  1          A      North
  2          B      South
  3          C      East

  **B:**
  Period    City    Sales1    Sales2    Sales3
   1         A        12        13        14
   2         B         1         2         3

  **C:**
  Period    Region   Sales1    Sales2    Sales3
   1         North     6        7         8
   2         South     3        2         5
```

`Sales1`, `Sales2` and `Sales3` are the same variables for `B` and `C`.

My goal is to left join data set `B` and `C` to `A` to get the required sales information `sales1`, `sales2` and `sales3`.

However, I only know how to do a left join and coalesce with 1 variable.

I.e.

```
proc sql;

     create table merged1 as
     select l.*,
     b.sales1 as s1, 
     c.sales1 as s2,
     coalesce (b.sales1, c.sales1) as sales1

from A
     left join B on A.period=B.period and A.city=B.city
     left join C on A.period= C.period and A.region=C.region;
quit;
```

My question would be if there a quick way to do this for the next few variables `sales2` and `sales3`?

Comment: Do the `sales1` (and `sales2`, etc.) columns even mean the same thing in tables `B` and `C`?  Can you show us some sample data?  Nothing wrong with your current `coalesce()`, assuming you want that logic.

Comment: Hi, yep they meant the same thing, I was wondering if there is a quick way to perform the coalesce function for the rest of sales2 and sales3 the code will get very long and tedious as the number of sales variable increases.

Comment: May I ask what is the point of listing the two `sales1` as separate columns, and then using `coalesce()` on the two of them?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to match the sales information to the original data set through geographic location by the level of granularity. If the first level of granularity in city could not be matched, then I would take the more aggregated form through matching by region level.

Comment: When you say "aggregate" I get the feeling that maybe you should be using `GROUP BY`, and that your current query does not reflect the logic you actually want.  Maybe update your question with some sample data and output to make it clear.

Comment: I guess the context of my questions would be that I have an original data set A with missing sales information. I next have data set B and C that are have sales information for different periods some of them appear both in data sets but at different level of granularity, city and region level. Hence, I would first do a match based on the period and city level first and if there are still empty information, I will then match at the region level,

Answer (score 0):

Your Query can be simplified just into:

```
proc sql;

     create table merged1 as
     select A.*,
     coalesce (b.sales1, c.sales1) as sales1,
     coalesce (b.sales2, c.sales2) as sales2,
     coalesce (b.sales3, c.sales3) as sales3

from A
     left join B on A.period=B.period and A.city=B.city
     left join C on A.period= C.period and A.region=C.region;
quit;
```

Output:

```
 Period=1 City=A Region=North sales1=12 sales2=13 sales3=14 
 Period=2 City=B Region=South sales1=1 sales2=2 sales3=3 
 Period=3 City=C Region=East sales1=. sales2=. sales3=.
```

Another option is to transpose all your tables using `proc transpose`, so the sales will be in the rows and the city/ region will be in the columns.

Data used:

```
data A;
input
Period    City $   Region $ ;
datalines;
  1          A      North
  2          B      South
  3          C      East
;
run;
data B;
input
  Period    City  $  Sales1    Sales2    Sales3 ;
  datalines;
   1         A        12        13        14
   2         B         1         2         3
;
run;
data C;
input
  Period    Region $  Sales1    Sales2    Sales3 ;
  datalines;
   1         North     6        7         8
   2         South     3        2         5
   ;
run;
```